# r glm function for binomial when x has more than 2 levels

Tags: r, glm

I know

```
glm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, family = binomial(logit), data = birds_poop)
```

will give parameter estimates for `x` {`x1`, `x2`, `x3`}.

What if there are more than 2 levels for x , how do I set the reference level and how can I get `glm` function to display parameter estimates for each level of x.

For example, lets say x1 has 4 levels how can I get parameter estimates for **x1-level2**, **x1-level3** and **x1-level4** assuming **x1-level0** is reference level.

Comment: If x1 is a factor in your data, r will do this automatically. If not, you can specify it in your model, ie, write `~ = factor(x1) + ...` and will fit the first level as the reference. You can change this in the equation by the `relevel` function (very handy for switching one level), but if you want to reorder them completely, I would suggest setting the factor levels in your data frame before fitting the model.

Answer (score 0):

R uses treatment contrasts by default. You can change these to other types of contrasts and further info can be found by looking at `help(contrasts)` and `help(C)`. With default settings the `(Intercept)` term will be the estimate on the log(odds) scale for a case with x1-level0 and all the other variables at their base levels or at a value of 0 for numeric variables. R will report parameter estimates for the factor levels that are not the reference levels. A common question is how to change the reference level which is easily done with the factor() function. You could also use `predict`.

You should read the help file for `glm` and all of the links. The other wonderful feature of the help pages is that they often contain worked examples and if you have further questions and are having difficulty formulating a good example than you may find that modifying one of those will make the discussion more concrete.